# Batch with 3 related objects

Tags: apex, soql, batch, query

Suppose i have 3 related objects: Continent - Country - City.
Country object is child object of Continent and City is child object of Country.
City -> Country -> Continent.

I would like make changes to a field on the continent object, based on a field on the city object. I want to use Batch Apex for this approach.
So e.g. Say City has a field called ''Population''. If population **on any city in any Country for a given Continent** is more than 50.000.000, then a checkbox (Potential Customers) on Continent should change. But if the Continent does not have any Country with any City more than 50.000.000, then the checkbox should be/remain unchecked.

So, I understand that for this approach I cannot query downwards, going from parent to child object since we are going more than 1 level deep, hence it is necessary to query upwards, from child to parent.
I imagine the query something like this:

```
global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
    return Database.getQueryLocator([SELECT Id, Name, Population__c, Country__r.Id, Country__r.Continent__r.Id, Country__r.Continent.Potential_Customers__c FROM City__c]);
}
```

The execute method gives me trouble. I do not know how this should be done or how it can be done the smartest way. I am still learning Apex and SOQL. 
My suggestion would be using inner loops,

```
For(Continent)
    For(Country)
        For(City) 
if(Population > 5.000.000)
 Potential_Continent__c =  true
```

But again, I am not sure how i can do this programtically. And there are probably smarter ways to accomplish my problem above. Can anyone help?

Comment: Are the relationships between the three objects master-detail or lookup? What is the data volume for Country and City?

Comment: Hi David, appreciate your reply. 
the relationships between the objects are lookup. City has lookup relationship to Country and Country has lookup to Continent. 
Data volume, I am not 100% sure. I expect somewhere between 100-200 records for Country. and maybe 500-1000 records for City, it could also be more.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need a batch class for this. At the data volume you mentioned

> I expect somewhere between 100-200 records for Country. and maybe 500-1000 records for City

you should be able to handle this with a couple of quick queries and run updates:

```
Map<Id, Continent__c> continentsToUpdate = new Map<Id, Continent__c>();

// First, find the Continents that need to have the flag set
for (City__c c: [SELECT Id, Country__r.Continent__c FROM City__c WHERE Population__c > 50000000]) {
    continentsToUpdate.put(
        c.Country__r.Continent__c,
        new Continent__c(Id = c.Country__r.Continent__c, Potential_Continent__c = true)
    );
}

// Now, find the Continents that have the wrong value for Potential Continent

for (Continent__c continent : [SELECT Id FROM Continent__c WHERE Potential_Continent__c = true AND Id NOT IN :continentsToUpdate.keySet()]) {
    continentsToUpdate.put(
        continent.Id,
        new Continent__c(Id = continent.Id, Potential_Continent__c = false)
    );
}

update continentsToUpdate.values();
```

Comment: Hi David, thanks for your detailed answer. 
There might be more records. I would like to stick to having the batch class. So i would need to have it in one query.